# std::enable_if_t works with gcc and clang but does not compile with msvc

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I have a friend function template `operator<<` that [works](https://godbolt.org/z/WGW7e48vf) with both gcc and clang but not with msvc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< T{1}, int> =0 >
class Foo
{
    template< typename Ar, typename R> 
    friend Ar& operator<<(Ar& os, const Foo<R>& foo)
    {
        return os;
    }          
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> i;
    std::cout << i;  //works with gcc and clang but does not compile with msvc
}
```

I want to know which compiler has the correct behavior according to the c++ standard. The msvc error says:

```
<source>(4): error C2972: 'Foo': template parameter 'unnamed-parameter': the type of non-type argument is invalid
<source>(6): note: see declaration of 'Foo'
<source>(4): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(11): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<T,__formal>' being compiled
<source>(15): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Foo<int,0>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: I think it's an MSVC bug to do with enable_if. Here's a similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902168

Comment: As a workaround, making it a type parameter `typename = std::enable_if_t< T{1}>` seems to compile.

Comment: Consider using `requires`, which is more readable, and probably isn't bugged.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a MSVC bug and has nothing to do with the `operator<<` at all.

Just mentioning `Foo<U>` anywhere with `U` being a template parameter causes the error because MSVC tries to check validity of `std::enable_if_t< T{1}, int>` immediately, even though no concrete type for `U`/`T` is known yet. This then fails.

MSVC doesn't correctly recognize that `std::enable_if_t< T{1}, int>` is a dependent type and therefore shouldn't be checked until after a concrete `U`/`T` is substituted.

See https://godbolt.org/z/ncb3va3ro for a reduced example:

```
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< T{1}, int> =0 >
class Foo
{      
};

template<typename R>
using U = Foo<R>;  // <- same error here
```

Comment: @Alan I don't know. I haven't checked https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home.

Comment: Just reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Premature-checking-of-template-validity/10491909